# The method setX(float) is undefined for the type Button

Tags: android

I just reconfigured a previously working project to work with an earlier version of android (2.2)... only to find that it won't compile lines like:

```
mybutton.setX(myfloatvalue);
```

complaining that "`The method setX(float) is undefined for the type Button`".. so my question is, what can I do instead? Is there a near equivalent?

Comment: Why would you like to use outdated API anyway? Is this **really** a necessity?

Comment: @Aleksander Lidtke: What percentage of still-being-used handsets would I miss out on if I started from 11?

Comment: More than 30% of devices in the field are still running Android 2.2 or 2.3. It is a large chunk of the installed base. These statistics are regularly updated and you can check this at http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Frustratingly, the pie chart does not differentiate between 10,11,and 12! It just says that *combined* they're 28.5%

Comment: @Mick - you're the dev here, up to you to decide. Just asking a question that is, imho, worthwhile thinking about :)

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Its not about outdated or updated API is about providing backward compat. Thats kinda subjective to me.

Comment: @Mick can you check out my answer? it should help you.

Comment: @superuser: can't try it till tomorrow.

Comment: @Mick ok, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Android 2.2 (Froyo) accounts for only 2.2% of users in the latest dashboard. http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: So you put a bounty on your questions but don't mark answers as correct in order to "save" half the bounty...

Comment: @Emanuel Moecklin: not my intention at all. Its not clear what the correct answer is... also its been a weekend and I've only just got back in front of my computer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `TranslateAnimation`. Use Nine Old Androids library for backward compat:

`ViewHelper.setX(button, xValue);`

View is not clickable after `TranslateAnimation` because only the "sprite" of the button is moved, but  not the bounds and layout params of the view, i.e clickable region. If you click on old position it will call the listener, weird huh?

You might want to use `ObjectAnimator` from nine old androids to move entire view structure to the position you want, and still the view be clickable.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use external libraries. Assign the left margin of the view to the desired x in `onAnimationEnd()` and have your view clickable again.

Comment: I just tried ViewHelper.setX(button, xValue); - the button was then positioned correctly - but not clickable :-(

Comment: When you say "Assign the left margin of the view" do you mean call mybutton.setLeft(), setRight() etc?

Comment: That will update your rectangle. Thats good option for HC and beyond. By left margin i meant `layoutParams = getLayoutParams();` `layoutParams.leftMargin` or `layoutParams.rightMargin`

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust the layout parameters of the button, and make sure the button is in a relativelayout. for the setX, set the layout parameters right margin to myFloatValue.
Here is a quick example:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

[setX **available in api 11**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29) and above.

To get around this, use a TranslateAnimation with a duration of 0 and the parameters that would give your effect. According to the [documentation of setX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29), it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Sherif says right things about setX method and maybe look setTop, setBottom etc.

Comment: I've just tried that - with setFillAfter(true).. the buttons appeared exactly where I wanted - but now they don't appear clickable any more :-(

Comment: @Mick You cant' move it because only the "sprite" of the button is moved, but  not the bounds of the view, i.e clickable bounds. If you click on old position it will call the listener. 

You might use `ObjectAnimator` from nine old androids to move entire view structure to the position you want, and still the view be clickable.